# Create a slightly modified copy of a Python tuple?

Tags: python, tuples

I have a Python tuple, `t`, with 5 entries. `t[2]` is an `int`. How can I create another tuple with the same contents, but with `t[2]` incremented?

Is there a better way than:

```
t2 = (t[0], t[1], t[2] + 1, t[3], t[4]) ?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would be inclined to use a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) instead, and use the [`_replace` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._replace):

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Test = namedtuple('Test', 'foo bar baz')
>>> t1 = Test(1, 2, 3)
>>> t1
Test(foo=1, bar=2, baz=3)
>>> t2 = t1._replace(bar=t1.bar+1)
>>> t2
Test(foo=1, bar=3, baz=3)
```

This also gives semantic meaning to the individual elements in the tuple, i.e. you refer to `bar` rather than just the `1`th element.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't seen the `_replace` method before.

Answer (score 3):

If you have large tuples and just wanted to increment at certain indexes without manually indexing:

```
tuple(e + 1 if i == 2 else e for i, e in enumerate(t))
```

As Jon commented if you have multiple indexes you can use a set of indexes you want to increment:

```
 tuple(e + 1 if i in {1,3} else e for i, e in enumerate(t))
```

Comment: You could use `i in {2}` to make it more extensible to other indices

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use numpy and build a list of values you want to increment, then simply add them together, for example:

```
In [6]: import numpy as np

# your tuple
In [7]: t1 = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

# your list of values you want to increment
# this acts as a mask for mapping your values
In [8]: n = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]

# add them together and numpy will only increment the respective position value
In [9]: np.array(t1) + n
Out[9]: array([1, 2, 4, 4, 5])

# convert back to tuple
In [10]: tuple(np.array(t1) + n)                                            
Out[11]: (1, 2, 4, 4, 5)
```

Comment: In this case, why not use an array throughout?

Comment: @jonrsharpe well you're right and we should, but OP's intention is to use tuple so I kept it this way for the use case. This is only an alternative way to show if using numpy, then increment any value in the tuple/list is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use tuple slicing, to build the new tuple:

```
t2 = t[:2] + (t[2] + 1,) + t[3:]
```